# Alembic autogeneration custom schemas

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, migration, alembic

Im trying to create table with custom schema, created in Base class.

Base class:

```
@as_declarative()
class Base:
    """Base class for all database entities"""

    @classmethod
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        """Generate database table name automatically.
        Convert CamelCase class name to snake_case db table name.
        """
        return re.sub(r"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])", "_", cls.__name__).lower()

    @classmethod
    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls) -> dict[str, str]:
        return {'schema': f'{cls.__module__.split(".")[-2]}_{cls.__module__.split(".")[-1].upper()}'}

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        attrs = []
        for c in self.__table__.columns:
            attrs.append(f"{c.name}={getattr(self, c.name)}")
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, ", ".join(attrs))
```

The problem is, that alembic autogenerated migrations just dont see the schema from __table_args_. I added `include_schemas=True` in both online and offline migrations.

Strangly enough, it DOES add `schema='STG_UNION_MEMBER'` in migration file, but no schema creation at all.

migration file:

```
"""init

Revision ID: 3d2d5e14ded1
Revises: 
Create Date: 2023-08-22 19:00:27.771231

"""
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '3d2d5e14ded1'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    op.create_table('union_member',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('type_of_learning', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('rzd_status', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('academic_level', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('status', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('faculty', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('first_name', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_name', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('date_of_birth', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('phone_number', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('image', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('rzd_datetime', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('rzd_number', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('grade_level', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('has_student_id', sa.Boolean(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('entry_date', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('status_gain_date', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('card_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('card_status', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('card_date', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('card_number', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('card_user', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('card', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    schema='STG_UNION_MEMBER'
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('union_member', schema='STG_UNION_MEMBER')
```

env.py (alembic):

```
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig

from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool, inspect

import profcomff_definitions
from profcomff_definitions.base import Base


config = context.config

if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = Base.metadata


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = os.getenv('DB_DSN', 'postgresql://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/postgres')
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
        include_schemas=True,
        version_table_schema='public',
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    configuration = config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
    configuration["sqlalchemy.url"] = os.getenv('DB_DSN', 'postgresql://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/postgres')
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        configuration,
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata, include_schemas=True, version_table_schema='public'
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Table itself:

```
import logging

from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column

from profcomff_definitions.base import Base

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class UnionMember(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_of_learning: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    rzd_status: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    academic_level: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    status: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    faculty: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    first_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    last_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    date_of_birth: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    phone_number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    image: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    rzd_datetime: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    rzd_number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    grade_level: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
    has_student_id: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean)
    entry_date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    status_gain_date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    card_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    card_status: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    card_date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    card_number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    card_user: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    card: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)

class Test(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, what i was trying to do is to force alembic to autogenerate custom schemas i specified (STG_UNION_MEMBER in my code). Upon searching i found rewriter object in alembic documentation (link: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/autogenerate.html#fine-grained-autogenerate-generation-with-rewriters).

Adding folowing code to the env.py file:

```
from alembic import op as aop
from alembic.autogenerate import rewriter
from alembic.operations import ops

writer = rewriter.Rewriter()

@writer.rewrites(ops.CreateTableOp)
def create_table(context, revision, op):
    """Ensure schema exists before creating the table"""
    if op.schema:
        op.execute(f'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "{op.schema}"')
    return [
        op
    ]
```

and changing both configure() functions in the same file:

```
context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
        include_schemas=True,
        version_table_schema='public',
        process_revision_directives=writer # Additional line 
    )
```

seems to be working for me.